# How to get the name of an attribute from a function whose result is being assigned to the attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.4

The question may be a bit convoluted, but let me give an example. PyQt does what I'm asking for in the `pyqtSignal` function. You can do this:

```
class Foo():
  some_attr = pyqtSignal()
```

`pyqtSignal` has a keyword argument called `name`. It's optional, and if omitted the name of the attribute is used (in this case `some_attr`). I want to replicate that behavior. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Start with [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).

Comment: already did, no luck so far

Comment: Then where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: the problem is that I'm not able to find a reliable way to get the name. I know that the name itself is stored in `frame.f_back.f_code.co_names` but haven't found a way to determine the proper index of that tuple

Comment: Your code you're missing inheritance from `QObject`. Locate how they implemented this weird weird [factory](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Factory.html) in source and try to make sense out of it perhaps. I find this really strange, and less explicit than it probably should be. What you're looking for is in the [setProperty](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#setProperty) method.

Comment: QObject has nothing to do with it... it does provide a metaObject but you need an instance to fetch that

Answer (score 0):

This was really killing me here for a while. So I tried something just for the fun of it.

Anyhow, my idea was that I should grab the line with code of the caller, and then compare that line to a list of all local names of the frame the call originated from. If I'd get a hit, that means that variable of local namespace is the one that called my class.

However, issues start when you have to start considering, what exactly is a proper match and what isn't. That boils down to a parsing/matching problem. It's likely a strong regex that looks for assignment operator `=` could do the trick? I just did it with `find` string comparison function in python because I'm lazy

But like I said, I find all this little wonky and strange...

Here's an example code of how a function retrieves the name of a variable/attribute that the result of called function is assigned to.

```
import inspect

def call():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    caller_code = inspect.getframeinfo(frame.f_back).code_context[0].strip()
    names = frame.f_back.f_code.co_names
    caller_name = [name for name in names
                   if caller_code.find(name)+1 and name!="call" ]
    return caller_name

class Test():
  attr1 = "sad"      
  def __init__(self):
    self.attr = call()
    self.attr2 = "sda"

class Test2():
  attr = call()
  attr1 = "adsa"
  attr3 = "sas"
  attr4 = call()
```

Output of this is

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.attr
['attr']

>>> Test2.attr
['attr']
>>> Test2.attr4
['attr', 'attr4']
```

Obviously, `find` matches `attr`, and `attr4` because in names we have both of them and `find` just looks for the first and last matching index and would find a hit even in "nnnaattrnnnnnn".

I do have to mention I doubt they did it the hammer to forehead style I did it in.... (I've not even tried experimenting with multiple assignemets, generator expressions, and other wild context in which your a variable could possibly be found)